# Determine where spark program is failing?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

Is there anyway to debug a Spark application that is running in a cluster mode?  I have a program that has been running successfully for a while, which processes a couple hundred GB at a time.  Recently I had some data cause the run to fail due to executors being disconnected.  From what I have read, this is likely a memory issue.  I'm trying to determine what function/action is causing the memory issue to trigger.  I am using Spark on an EMR cluster(which uses YARN), what would be the best way to debug this issue?

Comment: You can look at the yarn logs in the master node by executing this command: `yarn logs -applicationId <appId>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `cluster mode` you can go to the **YARN Resource Manager UI** and select the **Tracking UI** for your specific running application (which points to the `spark driver` running on the **Application Master** within the **YARN Node Manager**)  to open up the **Spark UI** which is the core developer interface for debugging spark apps.

For `client mode` you can also go to the **YARN RM UI** like previously mentioned as well as hit the **Spark UI** via this address => `http://[driverHostname]:4040` where *driverHostName* is the Master Node in `EMR` and 4040 is the default port (this can be changed).

Additionally you can access submitted and completed spark apps via the **Spark History Server** via this default address => `http://master-public-dns-name:18080/`

These are the essential resources with the **Spark UI** being the main toolkit for your request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-webui.html